# How to store image in SQL Server database tables column

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, t-sql

I Have a table named `FEMALE` in my database. It has `ID` as `Primary Key`, it has an `Image` column.

My Question is how do I store an image using a SQL Query?

Comment: Where would the image be coming from?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

give this a try,

```
insert into tableName (ImageColumn) 
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img
```

---

**INSERTING**

[image]

**REFRESHING THE TABLE**

[image]

Comment: Please explain what is bulkcolumn ?

Comment: `bulkcolumn` is part of the syntax.

Comment: I Tried this INSERT INTO Female (Image) SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(BULK 'E:\Vinay\New Folder (2)\ileana00002.jpg ',Single_Blob)as img , but it is giving error   Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'PMB.dbo.Female'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: the reason for that is your column `ID` is a *NON_NULLABLE* column. is it an integer column and set as identity? if not, then you need to specifically define column in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Please show me how to do that iam new to SQL and i need it immediatly.

Comment: my ID  column is PK and incriments 1 on each entry

Comment: OOPS THANK YOU it worked :D i did not set identity incriment and seeding property for auto incriment, but it worked thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you please show me how to insert other column Details too with the above query, that is with the image how to insert into other rows at the same time ?

Comment: [see here](http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=5_AEiJXbyiEC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=bulkcolumn+tsql&source=bl&ots=tSBnpEeca8&sig=YiGAw8fX_2Le0yiLAx8Oh_V9z7E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bgRTUfavGo2ZiAeY84DoDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=bulkcolumn%20tsql&f=false)

Comment: @JW웃 what is the format its stored in the image column? is it Base64 or any other format?

Comment: when I use WHERE in the query to insert image to specified rows it does not recognize table column names. why?

Comment: The path needs to be local to the machine holding SQL Server

Answer (score 12):

```
Insert Into FEMALE(ID, Image)
Select '1', BulkColumn 
from Openrowset (Bulk 'D:\thepathofimage.jpg', Single_Blob) as Image
```

You will also need admin rights to run the query.