# Insert manual data into database

Tags: sql-server

I have a Sql server database. Here the Fields are `Name, Branch, Age, Image`. The Data types of these fields are `Varchar,Varchar,Int,Image` respectively.

Now I want to insert data into this table manually. It is simple to all fields except Image field. So please suggest me how to insert data into image field manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store image in SQL Server database tables column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659835/how-to-store-image-in-sql-server-database-tables-column)

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I read the question... I am not asking how to insert data with code. So how it wold be duplicate ?

Comment: You are asking how to insert image into SQL table. There is not much code there... than what do you mean by "manually"? by clicking?

Comment: I am not asking on "by clicking" !! I have a datatable . I don't want to insert any data with code. I want to test my code. thats all. so tell me " Can I Insert Image Manually.. Without using any kind of code" ?

Comment: what you want to do? manually???? means no code?? or what??

Comment: @PouyaSamie I want to check my another application. Here I am using Image. That is inserted by another way. SO why I code for this. I just want a manual entry..

Comment: Well, at some point any method you'll use will use some code.... I struggle to understand what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**image field is binary field so you have insert into only binary data
so you insert only binary data if you have a image
 then convert to binary data after insert it**

write this

```
INSERT INTO
    [MyDatabase].[dbo].[tblPicture]
    ( Name, Branch, Age, Image )

    (
        SELECT 'a','amd',1,*
        FROM OPENROWSET
            (BULK N'c:\image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
        AS Picture
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @pankeel I know that image is stored in binary formate. but can you explain How to convert my image into binary data

Comment: what language you have used