# writing insert statement for image in php

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

My DB developer made me a db with a field in the SQL table as image type.
I am trying to take the image someone uploads and just insert it in.

```
$imagePath  = Input::file('image');
$image     =  $imagePath->getPathName();
```

$image returns the temp path name

```
$file = fopen($image, "rb");
$content = fread($file, filesize($image));
fclose($file);

$SqlConn =  "INSERT INTO [poll14] ([image]) VALUES ($content)";
```

But I get this error:  An error occurred substituting the named parameters. 
How am I supposed to be inserting the data in?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO poll14 (image) VALUES ('$content')"`

Comment: You also need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you have here is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is similar to your requirement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659835/how-to-store-image-in-sql-server-database-tables-column)

```
insert into poll14 (ImageColumn) 
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img
```

Comment: That worked great. Now how can I implement this in a stored procedure?

Comment: @user1899829 Did u manage to get the stored proc working ?

You have forgotten to accept the answer