# Get Image from a folder into SQL

Tags: sql

I have been searching this problem but I can't find the solution at all..I have my Query on SQL that gives me all the information for each student, I'm going to create an SSRS Report where it shows this information plus I have to show a picture of the student (Every student has a unique ID). I have the picture of every student on a folder, but I don't know how to retrieve it or show it on SQL or if it is even possible to do that..

So..Is there a way to get the image from the folder, get the path or something like that and show it on SQL? All of the images have the same name (ID) that the student.

Comment: Use an expression to create a concatenation of the image location, the name and the extension. Then use that expression in the report.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image to a SQL column in a table. The link below should help explain how to do it.

[How to store image in SQL Server database tables column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659835/how-to-store-image-in-sql-server-database-tables-column)